# pandas groupby when group keys are to be treated separately if key changed between them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, pandas-groupby

I believe the example of input and output will give the best explanation.

But in words - I have data I want to group by user and cluster, and extract min and max timestamp in a group and count the number of values.

```
user2.groupby('cluser')['time'].agg(['max', 'min']).reset_index()
```

Easy.. The *non trivial* part is that my group key cluster, if repeated after it was changed, I want to consider it as a new group.

I tried to "mark" when this changed happened (shift my cluster column and check when different and put a "marker column" with 1 or 0..) but still do not know how to proceed from there.

```
data = [[39, 116, 492L, '2008-10-23 12:45:24', '002', 1],
       [39., 116., 673L, '2008-10-23 12:53:22', '002', 1],
       [39., 116., 129L, '2008-10-23 13:01:17', '002', 2],
       [39., 116., 905L, '2008-10-23 13:16:25','002', 2],
       [39., 116., 541L, '2008-10-23 13:28:30','002', 2],
       [39., 116., 233L, '2008-10-23 13:41:33','002', 1],
       [39., 116., 0L, '2008-10-23 13:55:02', '002',1],
       [39., 116., 333L, '2008-10-23 14:08:35','002', 3],
       [39., 116., 229L, '2008-10-23 14:22:06', '002', 3],
       [39., 116., 225L, '2008-10-23 14:33:10','002', 1],
       [39., 116., 190L, '2008-10-23 14:50:58', '002', 2],
       [39., 116., 232L, '2008-10-23 14:58:23','002', 2],
       [39., 116., 540L, '2008-10-23 15:25:14','002', 2]]
pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['lat', 'lon', 'alt','datetime','user', 'cluster'])



    lat lon alt datetime    user    cluster
0   39.0    116.0   492 2008-10-23 12:45:24 002 1
1   39.0    116.0   673 2008-10-23 12:53:22 002 1
2   39.0    116.0   129 2008-10-23 13:01:17 002 2
3   39.0    116.0   905 2008-10-23 13:16:25 002 2
4   39.0    116.0   541 2008-10-23 13:28:30 002 2
5   39.0    116.0   233 2008-10-23 13:41:33 002 1
6   39.0    116.0   0   2008-10-23 13:55:02 002 1
7   39.0    116.0   333 2008-10-23 14:08:35 002 3
8   39.0    116.0   229 2008-10-23 14:22:06 002 3
9   39.0    116.0   225 2008-10-23 14:33:10 002 1
10  39.0    116.0   190 2008-10-23 14:50:58 002 2
11  39.0    116.0   232 2008-10-23 14:58:23 002 2
12  39.0    116.0   540 2008-10-23 15:25:14 002 2


output = [['002', 1, '2008-10-23 12:45:24', '2008-10-23 12:53:22',2],
          ['002', 2, '2008-10-23 13:01:17', '2008-10-23 13:28:30',3],
          ['002', 1, '2008-10-23 13:41:33', '2008-10-23 13:55:02',2],
          ['002', 3, '2008-10-23 14:08:35', '2008-10-23 14:22:06',2],
          ['002', 1, '2008-10-23 14:33:10', '2008-10-23 14:33:10',1],
          ['002', 2, '2008-10-23 14:50:58', '2008-10-23 15:25:14',3]]
pd.DataFrame(output, columns=['user', 'cluster', 'min time','max time', '# num items'])



    user    cluster min time    max time    # num items
0   002 1   2008-10-23 12:45:24 2008-10-23 12:53:22 2
1   002 2   2008-10-23 13:01:17 2008-10-23 13:28:30 3
2   002 1   2008-10-23 13:41:33 2008-10-23 13:55:02 2
3   002 3   2008-10-23 14:08:35 2008-10-23 14:22:06 2
4   002 1   2008-10-23 14:33:10 2008-10-23 14:33:10 1
5   002 2   2008-10-23 14:50:58 2008-10-23 15:25:14 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, create a helper column using cumsum to get the different clusters groupings, then groupby that newly assigned column with 'user' and 'cluster':

```
df.assign(clusterkey=df['cluster'].diff().ne(0).cumsum())\
  .groupby(['user', 'cluster', 'clusterkey'], sort=False)['datetime']\
  .agg(['min', 'max', 'count']).reset_index().drop('clusterkey', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  user  cluster                  min                  max  count
0  002        1  2008-10-23 12:45:24  2008-10-23 12:53:22      2
1  002        2  2008-10-23 13:01:17  2008-10-23 13:28:30      3
2  002        1  2008-10-23 13:41:33  2008-10-23 13:55:02      2
3  002        3  2008-10-23 14:08:35  2008-10-23 14:22:06      2
4  002        1  2008-10-23 14:33:10  2008-10-23 14:33:10      1
5  002        2  2008-10-23 14:50:58  2008-10-23 15:25:14      3
```

#### Details on creating helper column 'clusterkey':

Use `diff` to compare current to previous value for a change in values:

```
df['cluster'].diff()

0     NaN
1     0.0
2     1.0
3     0.0
4     0.0
5    -1.0
6     0.0
7     2.0
8     0.0
9    -2.0
10    1.0
11    0.0
12    0.0
Name: cluster, dtype: float64
```

Next add check to see where the values are not zero hence the current value has changed from the previous value.

```
df['cluster'].diff().ne(0)

0      True
1     False
2      True
3     False
4     False
5      True
6     False
7      True
8     False
9      True
10     True
11    False
12    False
Name: cluster, dtype: bool
```

Now, the True values mark the start of a new grouping of `cluster`.  Lastly, we can use cumsum to uniquely identify each grouping.

```
df['cluster'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()

0     1
1     1
2     2
3     2
4     2
5     3
6     3
7     4
8     4
9     5
10    6
11    6
12    6
Name: cluster, dtype: int32
```

And then, I used `assign` to create a column in the dataframe named 'clusterkeys' and I added this to my `groupby` method.

Comment: like a charm. can you please explain? the diff command is like what I have done white shifting and seeing when the value changed. but how the ne and cumsum create the "key per change"?

Comment: @korenmaliniak  Okay,  added some detail to this solution to explain "key per change".

Comment: The cumsum part is weird for me, why is it 11 for the true false and then 222 for the true false false? What is the logic?

Comment: Cumulative Sum.   1,1,1,0,0,1  cumsum to  1,2,3,3,3,4.  It is sort like a running sum. True get converted to interger 1 and False becomes 0.

Comment: Oh ok. The moment I thought of it as comulative sum I got it :) thank you very very much.